# RNN: Why is my loss declining although my gradients are zero?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, gradient-descent

I am using a recurrent neural network in Tensorflow with an AdaGradOptimizer. For understanding of RNNs I set the gradients to zero manually like this:

```
gvs = optimizer.compute_gradients(cost)
gvs[0] = (tf.zeros((5002,2), dtype=tf.float32), tf.trainable_variables()[0])
gvs[1] = (tf.zeros((2,), dtype=tf.float32), tf.trainable_variables()[1])
train_op = optimizer.apply_gradients(gvs)
```

I only have two trainable variables, so above quick-and-dirty approach should set all gradients to zero:

```
tf.trainable_variables()
Out[8]: 
[<tf.Variable 'rnn/basic_rnn_cell/kernel:0' shape=(5002, 2) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'rnn/basic_rnn_cell/bias:0' shape=(2,) dtype=float32_ref>]
```

When I run the network the loss is still declining. How can that be? As far as I understand the new variable values should be old value + learning rate * gradients.

Comment: maybe try SGD without momentum instead of adagrad.

Comment: similar behaviour, the loss changes up and down but stays around the initial loss.